# Insert to sql server table from field from another table and varchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to populate reqopt table which have two varchar fields (valeur, categorie), the first shoud be field from another table (mytable) and another should be a simple varchar ('prop').
I've tried this

```
INSERT INTO reqopt(valeur, categorie) (select distinct name from mytable , 'prop')
```

I got this error `Incorrect syntax near 'prop'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO reqopt(valeur, categorie) 
select distinct name, 'prop'  
from mytable
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME AS valeur,'PROP' REMARKS AS categorie 
INTO reqopt
FROM MYTABLE 
--WHERE CONDITION IF REQUIRED
```